# C++: How does format string vulnerability work?

Tags: vulnerability, c++, format-string

Lets say that:

```
char name[50]="TEST";
printf("%s",name);
```

Here in the code, the `%s` just says that the variable is a string. But why when we print out user inputs, the `%s` suddenly change meaning? What's the difference between the user inputting `%s` and the program printing out `%s`? Even if the user inputs `"%s"`, the `%s` still doesn't have the same meaning. So how did the user input got validated as a command, and it is possible to do the "vulnerability" inside the program? For example, if the user inputs `%x`, the program will print out information on the stack. Is it possible to do this within the program itself?

Answer (score 1):

The vulnerability does not exist in the way you've written it.  The vulnerability arises if the user input is used as the format string rather than the varg.

```
char input[50] = "%x %x %x %x";
printf(input);
```

Unless there is a bug in the implementation of the stdlib, vargs should not be interpreted as format strings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So why do format strings exist anyways? When will it be useful to do like printf("%x");?

And also, can similar things like SQL injection work, for example, printing out a variable given its name?

Comment: To format the output.  For example, printf("I have %d dollars and %d cents.\n", numDollars, numCents); inserts the number of dollars and cents in each %d.  The phrase printf("%x"); without a varg (the values after the first comma) to specify what %x should be would likely be a warning at minimum from the compiler.

Comment: re SQL injection:
Not that my C/C++ brain can immediately imagine.  Variable names are a human construct in C.  They aren't really tracked by the C compiler past a certain point, except for debugging purposes, if that's turned on.

Comment: @MysteriousShadow If you're familiar with SQLi defenses, then proper use of format strings is akin to using prepared statements.

Comment: @foreverska Ok got it. So basically one should never say printf("%x") with a varg. If that's the case, then why is that "feature" there? Like when they designed the language they didn't thought of the vulnerability and why didn't they remove it like the program simply crashes when that happens. I'm just trying to understand the origin of this vulnerability.

Comment: @MysteriousShadow Printf is not a feature of C.  It's in the standard library but I've worked on platforms where it was unsupported.  I doubt this was an intended feature of printf, more an unintended consequence of vargs.  As to why it's not somehow enforced, any sufficiently modern compiler will warn the programmer of these vulnerabilities.  With a flag like werror, warnings will be treated as errors and kill compilation.  Which is probably good enough in the incredibly permissive eyes of C standardization committees.  C++ on the other hand has std::cout, which does not carry varg baggage.